# App Transport Security disabled and still getting SSL Handshake Error

Tags: ios, ssl, https, app-transport-security, nsapptransportsecurity

I'm having trouble with making a connection to an API over HTTPS/SSL. I've completely disabled App Transport Security (ATS) using the below dictionary (despite the fact that the SSL certificate passes all the tests from NSCURL).

```
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

BUT: There's still an SSL Handshake error (below) that, when Googled, only suggests it's to do with App Transport Security.

`NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)`

I've created a minimal sample project that demonstrates the issue, [available on GitHub (https://github.com/samheather/AppTransportSecurityDemo)](https://github.com/samheather/AppTransportSecurityDemo). You should find that on running the project it crashes within a couple of seconds (straight after it tries to make the connection in viewDidLoad).

The domain that I'm trying to connect to is https://demo.heather.sh, and a sample URL that the certificate that has a response (so the certificate can be viewed) is https://demo.heather.sh:443/checkOnline.

Any ideas anyone?

Thanks!

Sam

Comment: Have you tried serving the intermediate certificate for demo.heather.sh? https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=demo.heather.sh indicates   the chain is incomplete and I'm not certain if this could cause the SSL failure.

Comment: *note:* I reposted this in a much clearer way from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36187787/ios-app-transport-security-not-accepting-tlsv1-2-connection-and-plist-exceptions?noredirect=1#comment60019224_36187787 since we now eliminated that App Transport Layer was causing an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described on [iOS App Transport Security not accepting TLSv1.2 connection and plist exceptions not making any difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36187787/ios-app-transport-security-not-accepting-tlsv1-2-connection-and-plist-exceptions?noredirect=1#comment60019224_36187787), the issue was that the server wasn't serving the certificate combined with the Intermediate certificate. Now that this is fixed, everything works :)

As Anand (above) says, a great tool to check this is: http://ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=