# Certificate error 9813 in iOS9, even if App Transport Security is disabled

Tags: ios, ssl, app-transport-security

I have problems with SSL errors connecting to a development server... I'm using Xcode Version 7.3 (7D175)

```
2016-04-21 17:52:39.835 xxxx.xxx[79353:1555019] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)
```

My AppTransport configuration is like this:

[image]

It's a development server, served via HTTPS, but with no valid certificate and TLSv1.0...

[image]

What should I do to fix my calls in the development environment?

- Should I fix the server?
- Should I change something in my app configuration?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It's best to use configurations as close to each other between Production and Development.

Therefore the best solution is to get a valid HTTPS certificate. 
It is easy and free with 
https://letsencrypt.org

Comment: The server is not managed by me and I know it's better to have Prod & Dev "synced"... But now, I simply can't :) I'm looking for a temp. fix for dev, since prod has already its own valid cert.

Comment: The thing is you might be out of luck. Disabling app transport security won't help with any SSL issue. Ex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36208890/app-transport-security-disabled-and-still-getting-ssl-handshake-error?rq=1

Maybe you could try over HTTP instead of HTTPS?